# CoreData: error: +[Toys entity] Failed to find a unique match for an NSEntityDescription to a managed object subclass

Tags: swift, core-data

I'm creating sample projects using CoreData to begin to understand how it works.
Everything seems to work but the console gives me this warning when I proceed with saving the data.

```
2023-04-30 12:07:35.027668+0200 CoreData_Es[45767:19614404] [error] warning: Multiple NSEntityDescriptions claim the NSManagedObject subclass 'Toys' so +entity is unable to disambiguate.
CoreData: warning: Multiple NSEntityDescriptions claim the NSManagedObject subclass 'Toys' so +entity is unable to disambiguate.
2023-04-30 12:07:35.027901+0200 CoreData_Es[45767:19614404] [error] warning:     'Toys' (0x60000396c210) from NSManagedObjectModel (0x600002d6d5e0) claims 'Toys'.
CoreData: warning:       'Toys' (0x60000396c210) from NSManagedObjectModel (0x600002d6d5e0) claims 'Toys'.
2023-04-30 12:07:35.028043+0200 CoreData_Es[45767:19614404] [error] warning:     'Toys' (0x600003978370) from NSManagedObjectModel (0x600002d24230) claims 'Toys'.
CoreData: warning:       'Toys' (0x600003978370) from NSManagedObjectModel (0x600002d24230) claims 'Toys'.
2023-04-30 12:07:35.028140+0200 CoreData_Es[45767:19614404] [error] warning:     'Toys' (0x60000397c9a0) from NSManagedObjectModel (0x600002d5e620) claims 'Toys'.
CoreData: warning:       'Toys' (0x60000397c9a0) from NSManagedObjectModel (0x600002d5e620) claims 'Toys'.
2023-04-30 12:07:35.028229+0200 CoreData_Es[45767:19614404] [error] warning:     'Toys' (0x60000396d4a0) from NSManagedObjectModel (0x600002d3a1c0) claims 'Toys'.
CoreData: warning:       'Toys' (0x60000396d4a0) from NSManagedObjectModel (0x600002d3a1c0) claims 'Toys'.
2023-04-30 12:07:35.028531+0200 CoreData_Es[45767:19614404] [error] warning:     'Toys' (0x60000396dfa0) from NSManagedObjectModel (0x600002d357c0) claims 'Toys'.
CoreData: warning:       'Toys' (0x60000396dfa0) from NSManagedObjectModel (0x600002d357c0) claims 'Toys'.
2023-04-30 12:07:35.028610+0200 CoreData_Es[45767:19614404] [error] warning:     'Toys' (0x60000396e890) from NSManagedObjectModel (0x600002d30dc0) claims 'Toys'.
CoreData: warning:       'Toys' (0x60000396e890) from NSManagedObjectModel (0x600002d30dc0) claims 'Toys'.
2023-04-30 12:07:35.028675+0200 CoreData_Es[45767:19614404] [error] warning:     'Toys' (0x60000396c840) from NSManagedObjectModel (0x600002d31c20) claims 'Toys'.
CoreData: warning:       'Toys' (0x60000396c840) from NSManagedObjectModel (0x600002d31c20) claims 'Toys'.
2023-04-30 12:07:35.028734+0200 CoreData_Es[45767:19614404] [error] error: +[Toys entity] Failed to find a unique match for an NSEntityDescription to a managed object subclass
CoreData: error: +[Toys entity] Failed to find a unique match for an NSEntityDescription to a managed object subclass
```

The data is saved and displayed correctly but I don't understand why the console gives me this warning

This is where I define the functions

**ToysDataManager**

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class ToysDataManager: ObservableObject {
    // Facciamo riferimento al modello di dati chiamandolo perfettamente con lo stesso nome del file 'ToysModel'
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "ToysModel")
    
    init() {
        loadPersistentData()
    }
    
    private func loadPersistentData() {
        // Ricarica tutti i dati persistenti del modello "Toys"
        container.loadPersistentStores { data, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Si è verificato un errore durante il caricamente dei dati \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func saveData(context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        do {
            try context.save()
            print("Dati salvati correttamente")
        } catch {
            print("Non è stato possibile salvare il dato")
        }
    }
    
    func addToys(name: String, price: Double, context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        let product = Toys(context: context)
        product.name = name
        product.price = price
        product.id = UUID()
        product.date = Date()
        
        saveData(context: context)
        
    }
    
    func editToys(toys: Toys, name: String, price: Double, context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        toys.name = name
        toys.price = price
        toys.date = Date()
        
        saveData(context: context)
    }
}
```

****UPDATE****

Thanks to the help of all the comments left on my question, I'm posting the solution to my problem.

To avoid instantiating the `ToysDataManager`  class several times, a '**shared**' `static constant` was implemented to be able to use the ToysDataManager class anywhere without having to instantiate it for each use, such as adding a new record to the data model

```
let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "ToysModel")

class ToysDataManager: ObservableObject {
    // Facciamo riferimento al modello di dati chiamandolo perfettamente con lo stesso nome del file 'ToysModel'
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "ToysModel")
   
    static let shared = ToysDataManager()

    init() { loadPersistentData() }
    
    private func loadPersistentData() {
        // Ricarica tutti i dati persistenti del modello "Toys"
        container.loadPersistentStores { data, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Si è verificato un errore durante il caricamente dei dati \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func saveData(context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        do {
            try context.save()
            print("Dati salvati correttamente")
        } catch {
            print("Non è stato possibile salvare il dato")
        }
    }
    
    func addToys(name: String, price: Double, context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        let product = Toys(context: context)
        product.name = name
        product.price = price
        product.id = UUID()
        product.date = Date()
        
        saveData(context: context)
    }
    
    func editToys(toys: Toys, name: String, price: Double, context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        toys.name = name
        toys.price = price
        toys.date = Date()
        
        saveData(context: context)
    }
}
```

At this point just call the method that manages saving data in this way

```
    Button("SAVE") {
                           
      ToysDataManager.shared.addToys(name: name, price: price, context: managedObjContext)
                    
      dismiss()
    }
```

Comment: Hi, are you declaring,  let entity =
    NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Toys",
                               in: managedContext)!  like this ?

Comment: Could be that you are using more than one instance of ToysDataManager in your app. Since it holds a reference to the persistence store (NSPersistentContainer) you should never have more than one instance

Comment: Can it be that you selected in your Data Model inspector for the entity `Toys` Class / Codegen "Class Definition", and you defined also a custom class `Toys` with `@NSManaged var`s? Both together give an error.

Comment: @ReinhardMänner L'unica variabile a cui mi riferisco quando chiamo "Giococanti" è questa... `@FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [SortDescriptor(\.date, order: .reverse)]) var toys: FetchedResults<Toys>` to get the data results and this for save data code Button("Save") {
                    
                    ToysDataManager().addToys(name: name, price: price, context: managedObjContext)
                    dismiss()
                }

Comment: I am talking about the class definition for your entity. The class definition can either be done automatically via the CoreData model in the Data Model inspector, **OR** by a custom class definition, **but not both**. Maybe you can check this.

Comment: @ReinhardMänner yes in `Toys`  in my data model in the codegen parameter `class definition`  is specified. Can I show you my code on pastebin? perhaps in this way I can understand better if it is not a disturbance for you

Comment: @ReinhardMänner https://pastebin.com/X1YCDq87

Comment: I am currently a little busy; maybe later.

Comment: Read my comment again, I looked at the code in the link and it has exactly the problem I described.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Indeed, after your comments I went in search of the solution and just create a `static let shared = ToysDatamanger()`  thus avoiding instantiating the class several times .. In my question I will update the modification for this particular case of mine